# What does int & mean

Tags: c++, pointers, types

A C++ question,

I know

```
int* foo(void)
```

foo will return a pointer to int type

how about

```
int &foo(void)
```

what does it return?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Also good to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c

Answer (score 58):

It returns a *reference* to an int. References are similar to pointers but with some important distinctions. I'd recommend you read up on the differences between pointers, references, objects and primitive data types.

"Effective C++" (ISBN 9780321334879) and "More Effective C++" (ISBN 9780201633719) both by Scott Meyers) have some good descriptions of the differences and when to use pointers vs references.

EDIT: There are a number of answers saying things along the lines of "references are just syntactic sugar for easier handling of pointers". They most certainly are **not**.

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int* pointerToA = &a;
int* pointerToB = &b;
int* p = pointerToA;
p = pointerToB;
printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, *p); // Prints 3 4 4
int& referenceToA = a;
int& referenceToB = b;
int& r = referenceToA;
r = referenceToB;
printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, r); // Prints 4 4 4
```

The line `p = pointerToB` changes the value of `p`, i.e. it now points to a different piece of memory.

`r = referenceToB` does something completely different: it assigns the value of `b` to where the value of `a` used to be. It does **not** change `r` at all. `r` is still a reference to the same piece of memory.

The difference is subtle but very important.

If you still think that references are just syntactic sugar for pointer handling then *please* read Scott Meyers' books. He can explain the difference much better than I can.

Comment: +1 for Scott Meyers books. Must-haves for anyone who wants to have a good understanding of C++.

Comment: Yes, they are both excellent books. Taught me everything I know!

Comment: Reference variables are thus an alternate syntax for *const* pointers.

Comment: @Bento: No, that's not correct. You cannot do this: ```int* const p = &a; p = &b;```, but you can do this: ```int& r = a; r = b;```. References are not pointers, const or not.

Comment: Consider the following code: ```int& r = a; r = b;```. If your assertion were true, then you could replace the ```int&``` with ```int* const``` and the code should still compile. Try it and see - you'll find that ```int* const``` is not the same thing as ```int&```.

Comment: @Cameron: I did not simply mean `int&` <=> `int* const`, but I meant that _and_ the other opportune substitutions — i.e., replacing `r = b` with dereferencing  `*p = b`. In this sense, the two syntaxes do the same work.

Comment: They look similar, but you need to remember that they have different behavior. For example, a reference can never be null. It's a bad idea to think that they are just different ways of describing a single thing - you will wind up with subtle and confusing bugs. Understanding the differences and using the two constructs appropriately will help you to write more robust code. I encourage you to read Scott Meyers' books for an in-depth discussion of the differences between references and pointers. That will serve you better than an extended comment on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 6):

Be careful here... you're walking the C/C++ line. There's a quite clear distinction but it doesn't always appear that way:

**C++**: this often means a reference. For example, consider:

```
void func(int &x)
{
   x = 4;
}

void callfunc()
{
    int x = 7;
    func(x);
}
```

As such, **C++** can pass by value or pass by reference.

**C** however has no such pass by reference functionality. & means "addressof" and is a way to formulate a pointer from a variable. However, consider this:

```
void func(int* x)
{
   *x = 4;
}

void callfunc()
{
    int x = 7;
    func(&x);
}
```

Deceptively similar, yet fundamentally different. What you are doing in **C** is passing a **copy** of the pointer. Now these things still point to the same area of memory, so the effect is like a pass by reference in terms of the pointed-to memory, but it is not a reference being passed in. It is a reference to a point in memory.

Try this (Compile as C):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addptr(int* x)
{
    printf("Add-ptr scope 1:\n");
    printf("Addr: %p\n", x);
    printf("Pointed-to-memory: %d\n", *x);
    *x = *x + 7;
    x++;
    printf("Add-ptr scope 2:\n");
    printf("Addr: %p\n", x);
    printf("Pointed-to-memory: %d\n", *x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = 7;
    int *y = &a;
    printf("Main-Scope 2:\n");
    printf("Addr: %p\n", y);
    printf("Pointed-to-memory: %d\n", *y);
    addptr(y);
    printf("Main-Scope 2:\n");
    printf("Addr: %p\n", y);
    printf("Pointed-to-memory: %d\n", *y);
    return 0;

}
```

If C had pass by reference, the incoming pointer address, when changed by `addptr` should be reflected in `main`, but it isn't. Pointers are still values.

So, **C** does *not* have any pass by reference mechanism. In C++, this exists, and that is what & means in function arguments etc.

Edit: You might be wondering why I can't do this demonstration in C++ easily. It's because I can't change the address of the reference. At all. From [this quite good guide to references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references):

> **How can you reseat a reference to make
> it refer to a different object?**
>
> No way.
>
> You can't separate the reference from
> the referent.
>
> Unlike a pointer, once a reference is
> bound to an object, it can not be
> "reseated" to another object. The
> reference itself isn't an object (it
> has no identity; taking the address of
> a reference gives you the address of
> the referent; remember: the reference
> is its referent).
>
> In that sense, a reference is similar
> to a const pointer such as int* const
> p (as opposed to a pointer to const
> such as int const* p). But please
> don't confuse references with
> pointers; they're very different from
> the programmer's standpoint.

By request, on returning references:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& function(int f)
{
   f=f+3;
   return f;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 7;
    int y;
    y = function(x);
    cout << "Input: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Output:" << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any good compiler ought to give you this warning message in some form:

exp.cpp:7:11: warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable
'f' returned

What does this mean? Well, we know function arguments are pushed onto the stack (note: not actually on x64, they go into registers then the stack, but they are on the stack literally on x86) and what this warning is saying is that creating a reference to such an object is not a good idea, because it's not  guaranteed to be left in place. The fact it is is just luck.

So what gives? Try this modified version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& function(int& f)
{
    f=f+3;
    return f;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 7;
    int y;
    y = function(x);
    cout << "Input: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Output:" << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Run this, and you'll see both values get updated. What? Well they both refer to the same thing and that thing is being edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know in C &foo, and if foo is an int, it will be foo's address, and can be pass to int* type. What I am confused is when it is used in function declaration, int &foo(...), what doesn't it mean?

Comment: "What you are doing in C is passing a copy of the pointer." No you aren't - you're passing the *value* of the *address* of the local variable `x` to `func` as a *pointer* argument. At that stage there are no other pointers so you can't be copying one. In the C++ example you are passing a the variable `x` to a function that takes a *reference* argument, so what you get is a reference to `x`. The implementation of these is (probably) the same: the address of `x` gets pushed onto the stack. IOW C *does* does allow you to use reference semantics, but it does not provide syntax to support them.

Comment: Yes, you are passing a *copy* of the pointer's value - a *copy of the pointer*. A pointer is a memory address in and of itself (therefore a "variable") containing another memory address. Attach `gdb` to a process and you'll be able to see this. Therefore the act of copying it is to assign a new memory space and put the value in. This is what pass by value means.

Comment: Pass by reference is explicitly a language feature. Language only. The end result is very similar, but it is important to highlight differences in the way languages work.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a reference to an int variable.

Comment: Does not need to be a variable (that implies it is named). It returns a reference to an int object.

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't C/C++ at all, as C does not have references, only pointers. An int& is a reference to an int. Also, you don't need `void`, it can just be `int& foo();`

Comment: This is what the document says, Texas instrument's TMS320C28x C/C++ compiler intrinsics, http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514c/spru514c.pdf, page 122, int&__byte(int, unsigned int), I guess it is different from PC

Comment: @Alfred: No, not really. The C and C++ languages do not have special embedded versions. The manual is wrong, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: @Alfred Zhong. No the documentation says the same as everybody else here.

Answer (score 1):

From Alfred's comments

> This is what the document says, [Texas instrument's TMS320C28x C/C++ compiler intrinsics](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514c/spru514c.pdf), page 122, int&__byte(int, unsigned int), I guess it is different from PC – Alfred Zhong

From the manual:

> int &__byte(int *array, unsigned int byte_index);
>
> MOVB array[byte_index].LSB, src
>
> The lowest adressable unit in C28x is 16 bits.
>   Therefore, normally you cannot access 8-bit MOVB dst, array[byte_index].
>   LSB entities off a memory location. This intrinsic helps access an 8-bit quantity off a memory location, and can be invoked as follows:
>
> __byte(array,5) = 10;
>   b = __byte(array,20);

This just means that the function returns a reference to an integer that acts like an 8 bit quantity. Because the value is a reference modifying will modify the object at the destination (just like the MOVB) instruction, while assigning to b will copy (just like MOVB) to the destination.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I am confused because I did exactly as the manual says, __byte(array,5)=10, and the compiler keep complaining "error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Answer (score 0):

just playing with variables to show you the meaning

```
int i = 5;
int * pI = &i;
int & referenceToI = * pI;
referenceToI = 4; // now i == 4
```

**EDIT**: References are just a syntactic sugar for easier pointers handling. at the assembly level, the code generated by the compiler returns to a you an address-pointer

Comment: Thanks! I know this. What confuses me is when it is used in function declaration, like int &foo(...), what does the function return?

Comment: It returns a reference to what you put after `return`.

Comment: There is no return, I think it is assembly language inside it, MOVB array[byte_index].LSB,src, I have no idea what it means

Comment: References are just a syntactic sugar for pointers. At the asembly level, i am sure that the function returns a pointer to you. I'm gonna edit.

Answer (score 0):

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references

This page says it succinctly!  A reference is an alias.  It IS the object, just by another name.  The previous name is still valid.  The reference is not a stand-alone object.  It IS the object by a different name.  You cannot operate on the reference because it is not a thing unto itself.  It is just an alias of the original object.

It is that simple.  Now you can think of it easily rather than the round and round in the above posts.

Answer (score 0):

int& is a reference.
To be more precise, a reference variable is simply an alternative name of an existing variable.

Example: Consider below code

```
main(){
    int x = 4;
    int& ref_of_x = x;
    // Now, modifying x modifies ref_of_x too and vice-versa
    x = 5;
    cout<<ref_of_x; //This prints 5
    
    ref_of_x = 15;
    cout<<x;  // This prints 15
    }
```